# Azure Command doesn't create AD User in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I am attempting to use the Azure CLI to create a user in my Active Directory. I am using this command:

`az login`

`az ad user create --display-name "John Doe" --password "dfdfsd34!234" --user-principal-name "john@mydomain.com" --force-change-password-next-login true --mail-nickname "Jonny"`

(I have obfuscated the UPN name)

If I run that from my command line, it runs exactly how I wish and the user appears in my Active Directory. If I place that command inside a Powershell script it fails, saying the UPN is invalid.

```
az : ERROR: Property userPrincipalName is invalid.
```

My version of Powershell is 5.1.14409.1005

Any ideas what I am missing? I originally assumed it's correctly logging into Azure, but then returning to the original shell?

Comment: I know this isn't how you'd do this for real, but as a diagnostic, can you add `az login --allow-no-subscriptions -u yourusername -p yourpassword` to the beginning of your script?

Comment: Does the user principal name you're passing contain a verified domain for the tenant?

Comment: Is this happening for all users or specific users only? Check out the special characters.

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: Seems to have been an issue with my Powershell. I had to reinstall Windows Management Framework and refresh the version of Powershell for my server.

Answer (score 0):

When we use the Azure CLI command `az ad user create` to create Azure AD user, please ensure you have provide a validated Azure AD domain. If the domain is not validated, you will get the above error. The default domain is `***.onmicrosoft.com` For more details, please refer to [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/438bf45c-8869-4ac4-b91a-cb0330a4ff29/userprinciplename-is-invalid?forum=WindowsAzureAD) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/domains-manage)

For example

```
az ad user create --display-name "John Doe" --password "dfdfsd34!234" --user-principal-name "john@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com" --force-change-password-next-login true --mail-nickname "Jonny"
```

[image]